# How can I catch when my application stops?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I hava a spring-boot application and I'm using quartz to create jobs. I run my application like 
**./bin/app start**
I need to catch in my class that implements Job when my application stops like:
**./bin/app stop**
Does anybody know how can I do that? 
I tried to implement `DisposableBean` using the method `destroy()` but doesn't work.
My main class in something like this:

```
public class Main implements CommandLineRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       .....
```

The Quartz create jobs and in my job create a variable "lock" like this:

```
public class MyJob implements Job, DisposableBean {
private RLock lock = redissonClient.getFairLock(jobName);
    .....

    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        if(lock != null) {
            lock.forceUnlock();
        }
    }
```

I need force the unlock when my application stop in the middle of execution so I need catch the stop in MyJob class not in the Main class.
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: https://medium.com/better-programming/cron-job-patterns-in-aws-126fbf54a276

Comment: Doesn't work how? Is `destroy()` not called?

Comment: Yes, I have in the "destroy" a log.info() but I can't see when I stop my application in the middle of the execution.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to attach an event observer to the application context, for example:

```
  public class MyJob implements Job, DisposableBean {

      public MyJob(ApplicationContext context) {
        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)context).addApplicationListener(
           (ContextClosedEvent event) -> onContextClosed()
        );
      }

      private void onContextClosed() {
         ...
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Luis, I'm trying to do like your example but I can't because of ConfigurableApplicationContext, cannot be resolved to a type. Do you know how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Try adding the following dependency to pom.xml: `<dependency>          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId><artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>      </dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@PreDestroy` annotation. Annotate the method with `@PreDestroy` which you want to execute on stop.

```
@PreDestroy
public void onExit() {
   //STOP FROM THE LIFECYCLE
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bishal, I'm try with your code but I can't see my log trace when I stop my application in the middle of the execution. Should I see my log trace?  @PreDestroy
 public void onExit() {
  log.info("In my onExit()!!!!!!!!!");
 }

Comment: Did you set your application log level to trace, or else try using `info` level logs. eg -`LOG.info("...")`, Write this `@PreDestroy` in the `main class` in which you have would have mentioned `@SpringBootApplication`

Comment: I have edited my issue. In the main class works fine, I can see the trace but I need to do that in my Job class because of my variable lock